# All connections on all I/O threads are busy

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-c++-driver

I am doing get query in cassandra in a loop, sometimes getting error "All connections on all I/O threads are busy" in c++ client. Load is also low.
**Server version** - apache-cassandra-3.11.2
**Driver Version** - c++ driver version 2.7
Related client driver configuration -
cass_cluster_set_max_connections_per_host (cluster, 20 )
cass_cluster_set_core_connections_per_host(cluster,2)
cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io(cluster,2)

Comment: Earlier my driver is cofigured with       cass_cluster_set_connection_heartbeat_interval(cluster, 10)
cass_cluster_set_connection_idle_timeout(cluster, 10). Now I changed to cass_cluster_set_connection_idle_timeout(cluster, 60). Now "All connections on all I/O threads are busy" error is not coming. Note : When "All connections on all I/O threads are busy" error came at thet moment total_connection and availabe_connection both were 0. Issue is not coming but I am unable to get the exact reason for the error. One of the column size was 12Kb.